# Retrieving data and relationships for JSON output

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm new to all of this and trying to wrap my head around Laravel. I have two models setup and one pivot table. I'm trying to output some JSON in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "question": "somequestiongoeshere",
        "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "question": "somequestiongoeshere",
        "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2"
        ]
    }
]
```

I've only been able to output either tags or questions but not in the format above. Any guidance would greatly be appreciated.

Question.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model {

    public function tags() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
    }

}
```

Tag.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model {

    public function questions() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
    }

}
```

Controller

```
public function index() {
    return Question::all();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent, by default, doesn't load relations until they're called (lazy loading). You need to specify relations to load, or 'eager load' them (opposite of lazy loading). For example:

```
$questions = Question::with('tags')->get();
```

See more [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading).

Comment: This makes sense but I must be missing something. When I add the above `return Question::with('tags')->all();` I recieve the following error. probably something stupid I am missing.
`BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1992:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()`

Comment: Apologies - it's `get()`, not `all()`. I corrected my answer.

Comment: thank you for your help, definitely got me going in the right direction.

Comment: I know my original question is answered but I have another related to this.I'm trying to eager load a many to many relationship which has a pivot table. when using the above code I get an error because it is looking for the id of the question within the tags table and not the question_tag table.Looking at that link I don't see anything related to pivot tables.

Comment: Ah, the with statement is looking for a method name, not a model. I got it working and it now makes sense. Thank you for all of your help!